# What does ABC in WCF stand for?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

What does ABC in WCF stand for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A == Address
B == Binding
C == Contract

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

**A**ddress, **B**inding & **C**ontracts.

(Ref: http://www.google.com/search?q=WCF%20ABC)